# Copy .csv file from Azure Blob Storage to Sharepoint site

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a CSV file stored in blob storage. The goal is to move this file into a Sharepoint site and set some metadata. What would be the best way to do this? The client does not want us to use Power Automate or Logic Apps.

I tried using Azure Data Factory but there seems to be an issue with writing data to SharePoint. I used the copy activity but the 'sink' to SharePoint failed. Does data factory support writing to Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

> The client does not want us to use Power Automate or Logic Apps.

Why not? This is the simplest way to achieve this, and is also better maintainable than for instance C# code.

> Does data factory support writing to Sharepoint?

Yes, it does. However, using Data Factory only to copy a file to SharePoint is quite a bit of overkill.

If Logic Apps are not an option, have a look at an [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) to automatically trigger when the file is created in Azure Storage, and have a look at for instance [Upload File To SharePoint Office 365 Programmatically Using C# CSOM – PNP](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/upload-file-to-sharepoint-office-365-programmatically-using-c-csom-pnp/) for a C# way of uploading a file to SharePoint.